# Selecting item from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the following contents:

```
$tester

 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(CategoryItem)#79 (17) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["addedInVersion"]=>
    string(4) "0.02"
    ["lastUpdatedInVersion"]=>
    string(4) "0.02"
    ["AToZ"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Page Name"
    ["scopeNotes"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["historyNotes"]=>
    string(13) "Added in 0.02"
    ["broaderItems"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
```

I want to echo out the name, if this case Page Name and then use this in an if statement.

I have  but this errors, I also tried $tester->CategoryItem->name but no joy.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some leaks in your php OOP understanding, you should fix them by following some tutorials like these ones:

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

Now to answer your question, your code should be this:

```
$the_name = $tester[0]->name;
if($the_name == 'whatever value you want') {
   echo $the_name;
}
```

first of all, your initial variable is a array, therefor, `$tester[0]`, then, this position is an object of the class `CategoryItem` so you use scope: `$tester[0]->value`

As for the last of your values in the class properties, `broaderItems`, this is again an array, so to access one of his values, you will have to call it like:

`$tester[0]->broaderItems[0]; //or whatever the keys you will have here`

Hope this helps! 
:D

Comment: ;) glad to help! take care!

Answer (score 2):

You need to access it like this:

```
$name = $tester[0]->name;
echo $name;
```